# what blog template/software is used

Tags: templates, blogs

Does anyone know what "blog template/software" is used in the blog http://laforge.gnumonks.org/weblog/?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Blosxom http://blosxom.sourceforge.net (based on the call to try and load `pb_blosxom.gif`)